# Authentication issue: Earth Engine Python using ee.ServiceAccountCredentials()?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

```
service_account = "cloud-service...iam.gserviceaccount.com"
key_path = 'cloud_credentials.json'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, key_path)
```

When running the code above, I get the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/gpfs/home/adrianom/.config/earthengine/credentials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extractByPolygon.py", line 8, in <module>
    import eefuncs.cloudmask as cm
  File "/data/gpfs/assoc/gears/scratch/adrianom/earthengine/Extraction/eefuncs/cloudmask.py", line 3, in <module>
    ee.Initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 112, in Initialize
    credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 241, in get_persistent_credentials
    'Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by '
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
```

I would like to avoid using `earthengine authenticate` and read from a file instead to run my python script, but I do not know what the problem is here. I can see it is trying to find my Earth Engine key file, but I thought that the .json file generated from my service account was enough. I also know that `earthengine --ee_config` is an option, but as I stated, I am running a python script that uses the ee module and this command does not tell the command prompt a default place to continuously look for a key file (right?).

Answer (score 5):

Follow the steps given on this page:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/service_account

**Most importantly "Register the service account to use Earth Engine"**
so what you have to do is register **"cloud-service...iam.gserviceaccount.com"** (i.e., your service _account) via this link:
https://signup.earthengine.google.com/#!/service_accounts
by entering the service_account email in your case **"cloud-service...iam.gserviceaccount.com"** in the Email field

and that's it, you are good to go without having the need to use ee.Authenticate()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Python script running as another user (*shiny*) on Ubuntu (from an r Shiny Server). In the end I had to run the following:

```
sudo -i -u shiny earthengine authenticate
```

I then simply completed the authentication via my web browser once and now the request for authentication is gone. I assume the authentication key is written to a file.

I am not aware of any other way currently, but you can contact [earthengine@google.com](http://mailto:earthengine@google.com) with your request.